# Array RGB manipulation

Tags: java, arrays, rgb

Lets say I have an `int[][] arrayA` and an `int[][] arrayB`. At any given coordinate in this array lies an RGB value. What I want to do is merge the RGB values from `arrayA` and `array`2 into a new array, `newArray`, using a weighted average method.

So what I'm doing is extracting the red, green, and blue values from each RGB value like this:

```
        curColA=RGB //suppose RGB is just the RGB in any given point

        int curRedA = (curCol >> 16) & 0xFF;

        int curGreenA = (curCol >> 8) & 0xFF;

        int curBlueA= curCol & 0xFF;
```

I do the same for arrayB, and now I want to merge them. Here's where I'm having trouble. Do I just do `newRed=(curRedA+curRedB)/2` or is there some other way to do this?

```
arrayA values:  { { 0, 0x44, 0x5500, 0x660000 } };
arrayB values:  { { 2, 4, 6, 8 } };
newArray expected values: { 0, 0x44, 6, 0x660000 } };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *weighted* average is usually done something like:

```
newRed = (curRedA * redWeight + curRedB * (1 - redWeight));
```

...where `redWeight` is in the range [0, 1], and represents the weight (or bias) towards red values in the 'A' array. It also represents the inverse of the bias toward the red values in the 'B' array.

Comment: And whats redWeight equal to?

Comment: @fprime - I'm not sure. The idea of using a weighted average doesn't seem to fit your expected output, the way I understand it.